# How to enable display_errors with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following *environment* on one server:

1. dev.domain.com for the development
2. test.domain.com for the tests
3. www.domain.com is the working production

For the development environment I would like to see all PHP errors (including parse errors). Unfortunately the PHP configuration is quite strict. It does not allow to set the display_errors within the PHP file. It means that

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

and all variants of it are not working. The following works fine within the .htassess file:

```
php_flag display_errors "1"
```

Thus, my idea was to do something like this:

```
if(HOST==dev.domain.com) {
    php_flag display_errors "1"
}
```

I tried SetEnvIf, RewriteCond, IfDefine and other variants, but without success.

Is there somehow a way to do it?

Comment: You should *always* be able to change `display_errors` via `ini_set()`

Comment: Do you have access to httpd.conf or at least to configuration of virtual hosts?

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, you can set `display_errors` using `ini_set()`. However, it won't help with parse errors as [noted in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)

Can you make changes to the VirtualHost sections for each site? If so, add the `php_flag` in there.

If not, why not just have a different `.htaccess` file per site?

Comment: I am able to set the `display_errors` using `ini_set()`. You're right, It just don't show the parse errors. If I am doing it in the .htaccess, I can see them.

Comment: I am managing i with a git,with three (dev/test/production) branches. I even want to handle the .htaccess file with it.

Comment: @Dennis If you have three branches, why not have the different `.htaccess` files in each branch?

Comment: To avoid mistakes during the merging. if I change something in the .htaccess of the dev, it must pass thought all branches.,,

Comment: @Dennis It shouldn't if you change and commit it in dev, then merge the other branches and change and commit.

Comment: In case of my git environment, I could add the line `php_flag display_errors "1"` in the post_recieve hook to the .htaccess, if I am pushing to the dev branch. This would work...

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore the .htaccess file within your version control system and create a separate file for each set of settings on each server.